# how to SUM two columns in different table between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

this my query but result false where number row different , that's to say whenever tableA select 2 row and tableB select 3 result is false

```
select sum(tableA.value)+sum(tableB.value1) ) 
from tableA,tableB 
where tableA.data between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09' 
and tableB.date2 between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the sums in subqueries before joining.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

```
select coalesce(avalue, 0) + coalesce(bvalue, 0)
from (select sum(a.value) as avalue
      from tableA a
      where a.data between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09' 
     ) a cross join
     (select sum(b.value) as bvalue
      from tableB b
      where b.data between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09' 
     ) b;
```

Comment: but error ( Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cross') ...  Iam using sql server 2012

Comment: subqueries must have aliases

Comment: @IvanStarostin . . . Yes, they certainly should have aliases.

Answer (score 0):

OK . So here's what my understanding is.
You are trying to sum up two columns from two different tables and get the sum of the summed up columns. isn't ?? Correct me if I am wrong.If this is the case then

A Simple Subquery Can Come To Your Rescue.

```
Select 
    (Select SUM(value) From tableA 
            where data between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09') +
    (Select SUM(value1) From tableB 
            where date2 between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09') FinalValue
```